# How to compare two objects in Junit

Tags: junit

I am new to java & Junit. Please help to write Junit test case to test the CargoBO method where Equals & Hashcode functionalities are not implemented.Basically i need to compare 2 objects using Equalbuilder class in junit.

```
public class CargoBO {
    public Cargo cargoDetails(String name,String desc,double length,double width) {
        return new Cargo(name,desc,length,width);
    }
}

public class CargoJUnit {
    Cargo cargo;

    @Before
    public void createObjectForCargo() {
        cargo = new Cargo("audi","des",123.00,234.00);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCargoDetails() {
        CargoBO cargoBO = new CargoBO();
        //assertTrue(cargo.equals(cargoBO.cargoDetails("audi","des",123.00,234.00)));
        Assert.assertEquals(cargo, cargoBO.cargoDetails("audi","des",123.00,234.00));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct test case for your scenario is

```
@Test
public void testCargoDetails() {
    String name = "test name";
    String desc = "desc";
    double length = 10d;
    double width = 100d;

    Cargo result = cargoBO.cargoDetails(name, desc, length, width);

    Assert.assertEquals(cargo.getName, name);
    Assert.assertEquals(cargo.getDesc, desc);
    Assert.assertEquals(cargo.getLength, length);
    Assert.assertEquals(cargo.getWidth, width);
}
```

You are testing a method which accepts parameters and calls a constructor passing those parameters. 
Your test should be verifying if the given parameters are correctly passed by the method or not.